# How to select from recrod by another record

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript2.0

I do have consts and record types combined like this

```
const PageType = [
  'type1',
  'type2',
  'type3'
] as const;

export type PageType = typeof PageType[number];

interface PageInfo {
  title: string
}

interface DetailsInfo {
  bla: string;
}


export const Pages: Record<PageType, PageInfo> = {
  type1: {
    title: 't1'
  },
  type2: {
    title: 't2'
  },
  type3: {
    title: 't3'
  }
}

export const Details: Record<PageType, DetailsInfo> = {
  type1: {
    bla: 'bla1',
  },
  type2: {
    bla: 'bla2',
  },
  type3: {
    bla: 'bla2',
  },
};
```

What I want is to be able to do something like that `Pages[Details.type1].title` <-- returns compiler error

Basically by providing a current `Details.type1` like `Datails["type1"]` (the string `PageType` will be dynamic there)  I want to get a related `Pages.type1`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here's reference code for what I believe you are trying to achieve and which shows a compiler error. When I first read your code I was very confused by the instance variables being given capitalised names as if they were types so I have corrected that.

Because of [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) there is no way to understand what entry a DetailsInfo came from after it has been separated from its lookup key (as implied in the function definition in my example). You need to preserve information of what PageType key is associated with any invocation or data item AT RUNTIME (i.e. as a value explicit in the javascript) if you expect to use it to control javascript logic (e.g. use it for lookup and retrieve something).

```
const PAGE_TYPE = [
  'type1',
  'type2',
  'type3'
] as const;

export type PageType = typeof PAGE_TYPE[number];

interface PageInfo {
  title: string
}

interface DetailsInfo {
  bla: string;
}


export const pages: Record<PageType, PageInfo> = {
  type1: {
    title: 't1'
  },
  type2: {
    title: 't2'
  },
  type3: {
    title: 't3'
  }
}

export const details: Record<PageType, DetailsInfo> = {
  type1: {
    bla: 'bla1',
  },
  type2: {
    bla: 'bla2',
  },
  type3: {
    bla: 'bla2',
  },
};

function getPageInfo(detailsInfo:DetailsInfo): PageInfo{
//there is a compiler error here and no known way to implement this function so it returns the 'correct' PageInfo
}

const pageInfo = getPageInfo(details["type1"]);
```

By contrast here is an implementation which DOES work, but you can see that the PageType value has to be preserved at runtime where you expect a lookup to be possible. I've no idea if this is the right kind of approach for your real-world case but it indicates what's missing about the original approach.

```
const PAGE_TYPE = [
  'type1',
  'type2',
  'type3'
] as const;

export type PageType = typeof PAGE_TYPE[number];

interface PageInfo<Kind extends PageType> {
  title: string
  kind:Kind
}

interface DetailsInfo<Kind extends PageType> {
  bla: string;
  kind:Kind
}

type PageLookup = {
  [K in PageType]: PageInfo<K>
}

type DetailsLookup = {
  [K in PageType]: DetailsInfo<K>
}

export const pages: PageLookup = {
  type1: {
    kind:"type1",
    title: 't1'
  },
  type2: {
    kind:"type2",
    title: 't2'
  },
  type3: {
    kind:"type3",
    title: 't3'
  }
} as const;

export const details: DetailsLookup = {
  type1: {
    kind:"type1",
    bla: 'bla1',
  },
  type2: {
    kind:"type2",
    bla: 'bla2',
  },
  type3: {
    kind:"type3",
    bla: 'bla2',
  },
} as const;

function getPageTitle<Kind extends PageType>(detailsInfo:DetailsInfo<Kind>): string{
  return pages[detailsInfo.kind].title
}

const pageTitle = getPageTitle(details["type1"]);
```

Comment: the `getPageInfo` is is something needs to be implemented?

Comment: Trying to fill in the blanks of your original posting, that's the function you would like to know how to implement, right?

Comment: I'm saying that based on that definition there is no possible implementation. By contrast if you had a getPageInfo(pageType:PageType, lookup:Record<PageType, PageInfo>=pages) signature (e.g. pageType is an actual value that's accessible) then you can do it.

Comment: Does that mean that it is a bad idea what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: No it just means you need to restructure your approach to ensure the javascript runtime has access to the information you want to use for lookup. It can't be done in the way you are attempting it.

Comment: I updated the answer with an approach which DOES compile but whether this makes sense for your real-world case it's hard to know.